# Open new socket connection in new console ,so we can chat with specific client only

Tags: java, sockets

I am developing one chatting application, having one server and multiple clients.
I want that,server should  chat with each client separately, that no other client can see it.
how can i achieve it? 
can we open separate socket connection in separate console?
i am new in socket programming.so please help me to sort it out.thanks in advance

Comment: So you just have one server running and then make only one `Client` class and run it multiple times to connect to the server. Your server should be able to handle multiple clients if you do it correctly.  Are you using and IDE or just command line?

Comment: yes i done it but,server will send response sequentialy to client. means if client  A,B,C  connect sequentially,then first response goes to A and second goes to B and so on.i want to send response to any one of selected client with any number of response.

Comment: I'm quite unclear on what you are asking my apologies but you want it so it doesn't send these so called `responses` to the clients sequentially?

Comment: i just want to maintain each connection separately. Such as in first console server can chat only with first client.and in second console server can chat only with second client and so on...